# 1-row 0.1" pin spacing connectors with good connect/disconnect cycles

Tags: connector, durability

How can I locate connectors with a good rating on connect/disconnect cycle lifetime? (1000+ cycles)

I've tried searching on google, and I've checked a couple of Molex series I'm familiar with, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I can not tell you how to locate these parts, but a quick search on Samtec's site and I was able to find a mechanical test report of 0.100" headers/sockets here: http://www.samtec.com/Documents/WebFiles/TestRpt/TC0733-1424_Reportrev5_elp.pdf

A TSW/BCS or TSM/SSM mating combination with 10u gold plating has been demonstrated to exceed 1000 cycles with minimal contact resistance degradation.